# VBA Copy paste a range after a special cell changes

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I am trying to copy and paste the values of a range whenever a cell in A1 changes.

For example, if cell in A1 (is coming from a formula) changes to "2016.10", it look ups the same value in A2:A14, finds it and copies the range B12:E12 (are also coming from formulas) and paste them as values. Or, if A1 changes to "2016.11", then copy paste the values of B13:E13.

Is there a way to do this with VBA?

[image: Please_see_the_Photo]

[image: External Data is coming from another Sheet]

Comment: yr thread is not too clear, but if I understand rigth why you don't use this formula for each cell (depend how many records) Be=IF($A3=$A$1;"yr formulas";"")

Comment: Hi Fabrizio, thanks for your reply. the formulas in cells B3:E4 are calculating the data which is coming from External source. External Data is updated each week, and it shows values only for current calendar week (A1). My aim is to record the values of the past calendar weeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the way to tackle this problem. Here is the code I use to help me:

```
Sub PasteValues()

Dim RowData As Long, i As Long

Set Data = Range("A2:A108")

RowData = Data.Rows.Count

For i = 1 To RowData

    If Data(i, 1) = Cells(1, 1) Then

    Range(Cells(i + 1, 2), Cells(i + 1, 16)).Copy
    Range(Cells(i + 1, 2), Cells(i + 1, 16)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, 

Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    End If
Next i
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking something like this?

```
Sub SelectiveCopyPaste()
Dim WB As Workbook, Data1 As Range, Data2 As Range, RowData As Long, i As Long, FilePath As String

FilePath = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office\RS.xlsb"       'Add your own file path
Set WB = Workbooks.Add(FilePath)
Set Data1 = Range("A2:A14")                                         'Change this accordingly
'Change this accordingly
Set Data2 = WB.Worksheets("RS_Summary").Range("Set the range you want to copy here")            

RowData = Data1.Rows.Count

For i = 1 To RowData
    If Data(i, 1) = Cells(1, 1) Then
        Data2(i, 1).Copy Data1(i, 2)                               'Change this too
        Exit For
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Nastya. I just forgot to say that if A1 changes to say "2016.10", then it should look up for this value in A2:A14 (in this case it is in A12), then copy and paste as values the row range next to it (in this case B12:E12)

Comment: @Toli First, please don't call me like that. Second, it does work like you want if you change the value in A1. Have you given a try to my code?

Comment: Please forgive me. My wife's name is also Anastasiya, and everybody calls here like Nastya, but I am so sorry. I didn't understand what to write here "Set the range you want to copy here"? I put "B2:B14", but it is copying the headers. Do you have any hint what should I put there?

Comment: @Toli The range where the values 113507, 234, 474, 9065 located. What range you want to copy by the way?

Comment: If A1 is equal to "2016.10" then B12:E12.
If A1 is equal to "2016.11", then B13:E13 and so on. 

If A1 changes, it should look up for it's value in A2:A14, then copy-paste the cells on the right side of it.

Comment: @Toli What value should be copied and be pasted in `B12:E12`? Where did you get these numbers: 113507, 234, 474, 9065? Are they constants?

Comment: THank you for trying to help me, Anastasiya. Let me answer.

If A1 is "2016.10", then the data which is in B12:E12 should be copied and pasted as values in the same place. In this case 113507, 234, 474, 9065 ..  . The cells in B3:E14 are calculated from another sheet and coming from external source. And after an automatic update one week later, A1 changes to "2016.11", then the data in B12:E12 just dissapears, and we can see new values in B13:E13, because in this case A1 will be equal to A13

Comment: @Toli The truth is my code works fine if I know where the external source path. You just change the expression before `.copy` to the external source path like `workbooks( ).worksheets( ).range( )` and add the statement `Range("B2:E14").Clear`

Comment: External data is coming from another sheet called "RS_Summary" of the same workbook "RS.xlsb". And all the data in that sheet is coming from external SQL source, and they are updated weekly. Can you help me how this Expression should look like now? This is my last question. thanks a lot.

Comment: @Toli Could you post the picture of your source worksheet? Especially the range value?

Comment: I added the one more Picture, can you please check? THanks you very much.

Comment: @Toli I'm not sure how a little information like that could be any help so you may need to change the reference range of `Data2` in my code accordingly. Have a look my edited answer. I hope it helps.

Comment: Hi. Your code helped me to solve the problem. I just changed few things. Thanks so much.

Comment: Do post your answer then here @Toli :)

Comment: I already did it, but some codes are not inside the Grey colored backround, I tried several times to edit, but without success.

Comment: OK, thanks. Now, everything is in Grey colored backround. This code worked perfectly. I just changed some details (columns, rows)accordingly.